# Belkin Router unable to ping local hosts

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ping

I have a Belkin Router I got on the cheap at RadioShack before it went down, it's a Belkin F9k1105V2. I use it as a router in my bedroom (192.168.2.0/24) while the main U-Verse router sits downstairs (192.168.1.0/24). I put mine on its own subnet because the main router seems to have problems with too many devices on the same subnet it will cause the whole thing to go down and I have to factory reset.

On my bedroom router I can go to the web just fine, it has a setting for domain name so I set something like johnnylocal or johnnylocal.com, but when I try to ping mymachine.johnnylocal from any other device on the same LAN I get ping timeouts and it's trying to go to some outside address. Pinging my numeric ip like 192.168.2.4 or mymachine.local works fine though. Just wondering if there's anything I can do, doesn't look like there are any other DNS server settings available on the router.

Comment: Any device on the LAN to any other device on the LAN.

Comment: Provide the contents of your hosts file which has `mymachine.johnnylocal` defined as `192.168.2.4` (or whatever you want it to be).

Comment: I'd need to do that on each machine then correct?

Comment: I only want to know the contents for a single client at this point.  If the content is the same, you don't have to supply or retrieve, the same information multiple times.

Comment: I haven't written a hosts file for any of them yet as I've been getting IPs by way of DHCP. I'm supposing the DNS on these Belkin routers forwards to the WAN DNS. On this internal router in the bedroom I've got a few machines, a Windows 10 Enterprise PC running on an i5, a MacBook Pro, a Raspberry Pi 3, and 3 lightbulbs (2 TP-Link LB130s and a LIFX bulb), also occasionally my Android phone (Samsung J3). Right now the hosts file is blank on the Win/OSX/Linux clients, and I can't get in on the IoT devices because they're simply UDP only access by firmware.

Comment: Here are what my ping replies look like btw from my MacBook (192.168.2.5) to Win 10 (192.168.2.4) on the LAN:
ping SIMON-SMALLI5
PING simon-smalli5.johnnylocal (104.239.207.44): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 104.239.207.44: icmp_seq=0 ttl=44 time=31.526 ms
--- simon-smalli5.johnnylocal ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 31.526/31.613/31.700/0.087 ms
ping SIMON-SMALLI5.local
PING simon-smalli5.local (192.168.2.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.4: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=2.740 ms

Comment: The IP of the first I can't do an nslookup on, but I did a traceroute and it's probably the DNS server over at U-Verse (the WAN DNS server isn't listed on my WAN facing router's page it's obtained automatically)